# Monogame - All effects in one file?

Tags: c#, monogame, effect

I am successfully drawing all of my geometry with an AlphaTestEffect and would like to apply shaders. I've built a shader Effect from a tutorial and can't seem to find anything on the web that answers my question:

Does monogame support passing separate effects with the same geometry to the Graphics Device, or do you have to perform all Techniques you intend to apply to a model in the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

After playing with my shader some more I got it working. Indeed you can run multiple effects on the same geometry. It should be similar performance to having all your techniques in the same effect but can be abstracted better.